# Flash Actionscript Game - Character Not Moving after Adding New Keyframes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am really new to actionscript and am having an issue with a project I am working on for school. The code that makes my character move (Right, Left, Up, Down) all worked fine but then I added a new Keyframe at the beginning of the project and created a scene to choose a character. I have set it up exactly like my teacher showed us but now that the new keyframe is there, I click the character and it goes to the gameplay but the character cannot be moved. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the code from the first key frame:

```
stop ();
mc_fox.visible = false;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btn_fox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn_foxHandler);

function btn_foxHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

And The code from frame 2:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

mc_fox.stop ();

var move:uint = 0;

stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydownHandler);
stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyupHandler);

function keyupHandler (event:KeyboardEvent) :void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        move = 0
        mc_fox.gotoAndStop (1);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        move = 0
        mc_fox.gotoAndStop (15);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        move = 0
        mc_fox.gotoAndStop (30);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        move = 0
        mc_fox.gotoAndStop (45);
    }
}
function keydownHandler (event:KeyboardEvent) :void {

    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && mc_fox.x < 889) {
        if (move ==0){
        mc_fox.gotoAndPlay (1);
        move = 1
    }
    else {
        mc_fox.x = mc_fox.x + 5;
        mc_fox.play ();
        }
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && mc_fox.x > 111) {
        if (move ==0){
        mc_fox.gotoAndPlay (15);
        move = 1
    }
        else {mc_fox.x = mc_fox.x - 5;
        mc_fox.play ();
        }
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && mc_fox.y > 270) {
        if (move ==0){
        mc_fox.gotoAndPlay (30);
        move = 1
    }
        else{mc_fox.y = mc_fox.y - 5;
            mc_fox.width = mc_fox.width - .9;
            mc_fox.height = mc_fox.height - .9;
            mc_fox.play();
    }
}
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        if (move ==0){
        mc_fox.gotoAndPlay (45);
        move = 1
    }
        else{mc_fox.y = mc_fox.y + 5;
            mc_fox.width = mc_fox.width + .9;
            mc_fox.height = mc_fox.height + .9;
            mc_fox.play();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can't be moved or is invisible at all ? Don't you miss a mc_fox.visible = true; on frame 2?

Comment: Hello Philarmon, Thank you for your response. The mc_fox is visible on frame 2 it just wont move.

Comment: Another thing I see is that when you press for example, RIGHT, you are checking if the mc_fox.x < 889 and then you check if it is moving already (it is 0) and don't move it but do mc_fox.gotoAndPlay (1); So it looks like you need press and hold the button to move ?